# Elastic Cloud vs Elastic Azure Marketplace Template

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am developing an ASP.NET application that will be hosted on Azure, and that will be utilizing ElasticSearch (via NEST).  Looking at the deployment options for ElasticSearch, looks like I can use the [Elastic Cloud](https://www.elastic.co/cloud/elasticsearch-service) to host my ElasticSearch engine (as an ElasticSearch service) and have my ASP.NET app communicate with it (not sure all the details at the moment).

Then I noticed there is an [Elastic Azure Marketplace Template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-deploy/current/azure-marketplace-getting-started.html) as well.  Does this use the ElasticSearch service in the Elastic Cloud behind the scenes, or is this really an engine hosted on Azure?  If the latter, I assume since everything is co-located on Azure, performance would be better.

Would like to know the differences between the two options, and the pros/cons for using one over the other knowing that I'll be hosting the ASP.NET application on Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The marketplace solution is just a "bunch" of VMs. So its essentially a shortcut to deploy elastic search on your own vms. whereas Elastic Cloud is a SaaS service, you dont have to manage it. you just use it.

reading: https://www.bmc.com/blogs/saas-vs-paas-vs-iaas-whats-the-difference-and-how-to-choose/